# Use azure key vault from within native client app

Tags: c#, winforms, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

Is it possible to directly use azure key vault from within a native client application?

I have a connectionstring saved in azure key vault and would like to access this one from my winforms app. 
I already added the winform to the azure active directory and have a client id for the program. Unfortunately I can not authenticate the program to use the key in key vault. I get the error:

"Cannot find the Active Directory object 'clientId' in tenant 'tenantId'. Please make sure that the user of application service principal you are authorizing is registered in the current subscription's Azure Active directory."

In azure active directory for native client application it is not possible to add an key on the configuration page. Is this the problem? Is my way even possible or is it only allowed for web api to access azure key vault?

Comment: Sounds like you've registered an application but not created a corresponding service principal.  You can do that with the `New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal` powershell cmdlet.

Comment: I have the same problem. Regarding power shell, forums say you should use AppID URI instead of GUID, but that only possible for web apps. Regarding the portal, a native app is not even listed in the apps list, while web apps do...

Comment: @BenV Youre genius!